# Что означает оператор умножения рядом с массивом?

Tags: kotlin, syntax

Непонятно именно та строка где написано блок `if (listOf(*board)`, что здесь означает оператор умножения

```kotlin
private lateinit var board: Array<String?>
    
for (a in 0..8) {
    if (listOf(*board).contains((a + 1).toString())) { 
        break
    } else if (a == 8) return "draw"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не оператор умножения - это [spread](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) оператор. Он нужен для распаковки массива, в данном случае массива `board` в `list`.